# Tkinter Retrieve File Paths after Showing File Dialogue

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Can someone help me figure out how it is possible to save file paths selected from a file dialogue box with tkinter. I feel like the code is close, but when I go to verify that the file names are in a list--I do not see the files expected. I will be using the list of files later to run another function that does something to the files.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

# create the root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('xxx Analytics')
root.resizable(True, True)
root.geometry('300x350')

#Give the Window a Header
w = tk.Label(root, text="Welcome to the GmLogger Analytics App!")

def select_files():
    filetypes = (
        ('text files', '*.txt'),
        ('All files', '*.*'))

    filenames = fd.askopenfilenames(
        title='Open files',
        initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)

    showinfo(
        title='Selected Files',
        message=filenames)
    
    return filenames

filePaths = []
def handleFiles():
    path = select_files()
    var = root.tk.splitlist(path)
    for f in var:
        filePaths.append(f)

# open button
openButton = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Open Files',
    command=handleFiles)

#Create the Check Boxes for which types of logs to process
v1 = IntVar()
v2 = IntVar()
v3 = IntVar()
v4 = IntVar()
v5 = IntVar()
v6 = IntVar()
C1 = Checkbutton(root, text = "xxx", variable = v1)
C2 = Checkbutton(root, text = "xxx", variable = v2)
C3 = Checkbutton(root, text = "xxx", variable = v3)
C4 = Checkbutton(root, text = "xxx", variable = v4)
C5 = Checkbutton(root, text = "xxx", variable = v5)
C6 = Checkbutton(root, text = "xxx", variable = v6)

#Place the various objects in
C1.place(x=100, y=100)
C2.place(x=180, y=100)
C3.place(x=100, y=150)
C4.place(x=180, y=150)
C5.place(x=100, y=200)
C6.place(x=180, y=200)
w.place(x=55, y=15)
openButton.place(x=125, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem actually? *"I do not see the files expected"*, so what do you expect?

Comment: I thought that filePaths would have a list of files that are selected in the file dialogue box.

Comment: Yes it has when I executed your code. I just wonder why you copy them from a list `path` to another list `filePaths` inside `handleFiles()`.

Comment: nevermind - I am an idiot. Figured out the problem and fixed my redundant code.